# create a loop to add 40 everytime a value is called

Tags: swift, for-loop, constraints, counter, var

I am positioning 3 uibttons with the same height and wideth and same x value the only thing I want change is that I want each uibutton added 40 positivie it to seperate it. I would think there is some way to do this with a loop instead of doing this manually like i did below. I want (equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 0), to be replaced with yP plus 40 everytime it is called.

```
   var yP = 0


    undoButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
       undoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 0),
       undoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
       undoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

       clearButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
       clearButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 40),
       clearButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
       clearButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

       color.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
       color.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 80),
       color.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
       color.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
func setConstraints() {
    var yPosition: CGFloat = 0

    [undoButton, clearButton, color].forEach { button in
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : yPosition),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        ])
        yPosition += 40
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741091/create-a-loop-to-space-2-different-objects-on-a-uiviewcontroller? It's similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enumerated` method to loop through the indices and the buttons at the same time. You'll need the indices to calculate the top constraint. You should also activate your constraints.

```
for (index, button) in [undoButton, clearButton, color].enumerated() {
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25).isActive = true
    // note this line
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : index * 40).isActive = true 
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Can you look at this question stackoverflow.com/questions/58741091/…? It's similar.