# create a loop to space 2 different objects on a uiviewcontroller

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, nslayoutconstraint, cgfloat

My code below does exactly what I am looking for the problem is it just does this in a uibtton. I would like to do the same thing with 2 uitextfields and 2 uilabels. So textfield to uilabel to textfield to uilabel. I assume you would just have to change "button in" but I dont know what to change it with. I want the objects spaced 40 between each other just like below.

```
func setConstraints() {
var yPosition: CGFloat = 0

[undoButton, clearButton, color].forEach { button in
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : yPosition),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
    ])
    yPosition += 40
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your text fields and labels in the desired order in an array, and replace the `[undoButton, clearButton, color]` part with it. You technically don't *need* to change the `button in` part, as it is just a variable name.

```
[textField1, label1, textField2, label2].forEach { view in
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :25),
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : yPosition),
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(widthBox)),
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
    ])
    yPosition += 40
}
```

Note that [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) might make your life much easier. I suggest you have a look at how to use that.